# Custom UITableVIewCell initialization not called

Tags: ios, uitableview, initialization

I have custom UiTablleviewCell with some images and labels, and I would like to have rotated label in tableview cell...so I would like to edit initWithStyle method, but it seems like it's never called.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)stylereuseIdentifier:(NSString*)reuseIdentifier{
NSLog(@"creating cell");
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self)
{
}
return self;}
```

but in my log, I cant see this message. In tableview I have standard cellForRow method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"messagesCell";
    TBCellMessagesCell *cell = (TBCellMessagesCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    // smt stuff

    return cell;
}
```

so I'm wondering how does tableview initialize tableviewcells, I can think about some workarounds but I would like to have it clean.
Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the cells come from a storyboard or nib file, then `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier` is not called, `initWithCoder:` is called instead.

Here's a typical implementation of an overwritten `initWithCoder:`:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
       // Do your custom initialization here
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Will not work if you need to access IBOutlet during custom initialization.**

Comment: Thank you, this is an answer, I have been searching.

Comment: If accessing IBOutlets doesn't work within this method, what is the best place to for UI-related code that should be run during initialization?

Comment: @Julian it is best to use the `awakeFromNib` as @VinceBurn mentioned below if you are using IBOutlets. I use it and saw an increase in performance

Answer (score 8):

You might also consider the [awakeFromNib](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html) method if you need to talk with IBOutlet.

> **Discussion**
>   The nib-loading infrastructure sends an awakeFromNib message to each object recreated from a nib archive, but only after all the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized. When an object receives an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and action connections already established.