# animated image wipe for waveform color change

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiimage

I have a `UIImage` of a waveform that is created from the samples of an audio file.  The waveform is blue with a white background.  I want the blue waveform to change to red as the audio is playing to indicate the progress. If I have two UIImage's of the same waveform: one in blue and one in red - is there some kind of animated image wipe I can do to achieve this?

I've been able to achieve this when the waveform is a `UIView` and I simply draw a red UIView waveform over my blue UIView waveform, but if I have multiple waveforms (which i do - in a tableview), this takes my CPU usage over 95% and causes a lot of lag - even when no audio is playing.  I believe if i go the UIImage route, things will be a lot smoother since I just have static images.

Any tips?

Comment: You can use transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion: to do a cross fade between two images. See my answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370695/uiimage-is-not-transitioning-using-fade-with-animation-block-transition/24371092#24371092

Comment: That might work if I can fade out/in from left to right.  is that possible?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're looking for a wipe effect going from one side to the other? I don't think you can do that with that method. Have you thought about turning your audio data into a UIBezierPath? You can animate the stroke of a bezier path.

Comment: In the earlier stages I used a UIBezierPath to render the waveform and then captured it as an image and displayed the image in my tableview cells.  I'm not very sure, but I think working with two static images isn't as heavy on the CPU as drawing UIBezierPath's over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to do this is to have two UIImageViews one on top of the other, and animate a mask on the top one to make it disappear in a left to right manner, thus revealing the image underneath. In a test app, I have the image view with the red image on top of the one with the blue.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *redImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blueImageView;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIBezierPath *maskPath;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, self.redImageView.bounds.size.height)];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    maskLayer.frame = self.redImageView.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = self.maskPath.CGPath;
    self.redImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    [self performSelector:@selector(enlargeMask:) withObject:maskLayer afterDelay:2];
}

-(void)enlargeMask:(CAShapeLayer *) shapeLayer {

    UIBezierPath *newPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.redImageView.bounds];
    CABasicAnimation* pathAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"path"];
    pathAnim.fromValue = (id)self.maskPath.CGPath;
    pathAnim.toValue = (id)newPath.CGPath;
    pathAnim.duration = 1;
    shapeLayer.path = newPath.CGPath;
    [shapeLayer addAnimation:pathAnim forKey:@"path"];

}
```

Comment: I'm reading the apple documentation for `CAShapeLayer`.  To simply put it - it draws a spline?

Comment: @Brosef, don't worry about the definition, it draws a shape. In my answer it's just a rectangle, so that as you increase its width, it masks the entire blue trace in a sweep from left to right.

Comment: Gotcha.  I implemented your code exactly as you wrote it with the redImageView on top of the blueImageView.  I noticed that first the blue view appears then the red view comes across from left to right, covering the blue view.  Based on how you described it, I was expecting the red view to disappear, revealing the blue view beneath it.

Comment: @Brosef, that is what should happen, except that the red view isn't actually covering the blue view, the red view is still underneath the blue -- what's happening is that the blue view is being masked, so that it reveals what's underneath. Is this the effect you were going for?

Comment: Yes it works perfectly.  What I'm trying to do is trigger the enlargeMask method in my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.  I can get it to work for one cell, but it keeps repeating the effect for the old cell, even when I tap on a new cell.

Comment: @Brosef, my code was just for a single view. If you want to apply it to cells, then the code I have in viewDidLoad should probably be in a custom cell's init method, and the enlargeMask method should be in  the cell class as well. Then just call that method in didSelectRowAtIndexPath on the selected cell.

Comment: hmm this is tougher than i thought.  Since my cells come from a nib file `initWithCoder:` is called instead of `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier`.  According to the answer below, I can't access any of my IBOutlets during initialization http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313611/custom-uitableviewcell-initialization-not-called

Comment: Okay got it working by moving all the code you had in `viewDidLoad` to `awakeFromNib`.  I have a question: in your code the redImageView is being masked, right?  Based on this `self.redImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;` yet in the comments you say "the blue view is being masked".  Also, in your answer you say "image view with the red image on top of the one with the blue." but in the comments you say "the red view is still underneath the blue". Sorry kind of confused about this.

Comment: @Brosef, sorry for the confusion. I changed the way I was doing it, and forgot what I had done. I have the red view on top of the blue view, and it is the red view that's being masked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57113/discussion-between-brosef-and-rdelmar).